# SQL Insert multiple row with only one varying data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I wanna insert muliples rows with a single insert, but only the last data is mutable from a list.
Like this.

```
INSERT INTO TB_TEMPLATE (
    ID_BENEFICIO,ID_PROGRAMA,DDD
)VALUES ('42','78', X)
```

But the value from X is a list like

```
11,15,17,19,24,43,54,65
```

Can be done with a single insert?

All datas are String.

Comment: Do you want multiple rows, one for each value?  Or do you want to insert a nested table?

Comment: are you trying to convert X to a comma seperated string?

Comment: Can you add your expected output?

Comment: It seems you are tying to insert records to nested table. Check the link : https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:454569300346027174

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff multiple Rows

Comment: @gilmishal no, the X is only a representative what will change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will work, assuming you are hard-coding the X value (and assuming the values are NUMBER, so they must be converted to VARCHAR2 before insertion - this is done with `to_char()`). Adapt as needed. If the list already exists as a column in a table, select that column from the table instead of "`union all`" from `dual`.

```
INSERT INTO TB_TEMPLATE (
    ID_BENEFICIO,ID_PROGRAMA,DDD
)
with 
     value_list ( x ) as (
       select 11 from dual union all
       select 15 from dual union all
       select 17 from dual union all
       select 19 from dual             -- etc.
     )
select '42', '78', to_char(x)
from   value_list
;
```

Or perhaps:

```
INSERT INTO TB_TEMPLATE (
    ID_BENEFICIO,ID_PROGRAMA,DDD
)
with 
     value_list ( x ) as (
       select column_value
       from   table(sys.odcinumberlist(11,15,17,19,24,43,54,65))
     )
select '42', '78', to_char(x)
from   value_list
;
```

Comment: Thx, that´s worked. But i thought there was a easy way :P.

Comment: OK... I'll add a bit to the Answer, perhaps that's what you were looking for? Will be added in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO TB_TEMPLATE (ID_BENEFICIO,ID_PROGRAMA,DDD)
SELECT '42','78',
       CASE LEVEL WHEN 1 THEN '11'
                  WHEN 2 THEN '15'
                  WHEN 3 THEN '17'
                  WHEN 4 THEN '19'
                  WHEN 5 THEN '24'
                  WHEN 6 THEN '43'
                  WHEN 7 THEN '54'
                  WHEN 8 THEN '65'
        END
FROM DUAL
Connect BY LEVEL <= 8;
```

Comment: One correction done, still missing the closing ) after the column name list :-)